# Updating bootstrap to 5 turns emptyPlaceholder in file-drag-drop into a grey loading block

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I use an ngx-file-drag-drop ( https://github.com/telebroad/ngx-file-drag-drop) and after updating bootstrap from 4 to 5.2.0 I see that the placeholder text is now a grey loading block. How can I can read the placeholder text like before? Here you see two images (first one after update, second one before update):

[image: After update]

[image: before update]

And here is the code:

```
 <div class="dx-field">
      <div class="dx-field-label">Dokumente: <star-red></star-red></div>
      <div class="dx-field-value">
        <div class="help-field">
          <ngx-file-drag-drop
            emptyPlaceholder="Datei ablegen oder zur Auswahl klicken."
            formControlName="anhaenge"
            accept="{{ acceptedExtensions }}"
            displayFileSize
            multiple
          >
          </ngx-file-drag-drop>
        </div>
        <validation-msg
          [msgs]="validator.messages(form.controls.anhaenge)"
        ></validation-msg>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I think it has something to do with this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/placeholders/

but I just want to see a text you can read and not a grey loading block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a conflict, the placeholder of that component is a `span` with class `placeholder`, same class that Bootstrap uses.

**Option 1** is to get the npm package and modify the source code and change the class name. [Here's the HTML source.](https://github.com/telebroad/ngx-file-drag-drop/blob/master/projects/ngx-file-drag-drop/src/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop/ngx-file-drag-drop.component.html) Note you will also have to change the class name in the CSS, it's in the same folder as the HTML. Then rebuild and import in your project.

**Option 2** Overwrite Bootstrap CSS:

```
.placeholder {
   cursor: pointer;
   background: none;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

That should do, but here's the full (default) Bootstrap placeholder CSS in case you need it:

```
.placeholder {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: wait;
    background-color: currentcolor;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

**Option 3** Use JavaScript to remove the class `placeholder` (and replace it with another class name which you can use as a new CSS selector and display the text however you like).

**Option 4** Remove the placeholder component from Bootstrap and recompile.

I'd go with #2.